# How to partition the array into exactly K non-empty subarrays such that the sum of values of each subarray is equal?

Tags: python

You are given an array A of size N, with all values as non-negative integers. Bodega asked you whether it is possible to partition the array into exactly K non-empty subarrays such that the sum of values of each subarray is equal. If it is possible print "Yes", otherwise print "No".

Note:
Every element of the array should belong to exactly one subarray in the partition.

Sample:

3 0 1 2 0 0 6 0 1 5

Sample Output 2:

Yes

Explanation:

The array can be partitioned as {3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {6}, {0, 1, 5}.

My code :

```
listt = [3,0,1,2,0,0,6,0,1,5]
# listt.sort()
# listt = [i for i in listt if i != 0]

def find_next_sum(summ,listt,last_index,counter):
    if last_index == 0: #i.e if we are just starting with our listt
    #start iterating        
        for i in range(last_index,len(listt)-1):
            #start journey with first sum as 0:i
            print("reset : last_index:",i+1,"sum:",sum(listt[0:i+1]))
            result = find_next_sum(sum(listt[0:i+1]),listt,i+1,1)
            print(result)
        #if we have completed above loop and still last_index == 0
        #that means its not possible
        
    else:
        # print('else')
        #else if we already have a sum find next summ that match
        #starting from last index of previous sum
        for j in range(last_index,len(listt)):
            next_summ = sum(listt[last_index:j+1])
            print("current_sum:",summ,"next_sum:",next_summ,"last_index:",last_index,"end_index:",j+1)

            if summ == next_summ:
                if j+1 == len(listt):
                    #if we have reached end of list and sums match
                    # print('Yes')
                    return 'Yes'
                if j+1 < len(listt):
                    # find next next sum
                    # print('find next_sum')
                    find_next_sum(next_summ,listt,j+1,counter+1)                

            elif summ != next_summ:
                if next_summ<summ and j+1 < len(listt): 
                    # find new next sum
                    # print('continue')
                    continue
                if j+1 == len(listt):
                    #give up
                    # print('No')
                    return 'No'
            # reset or find new first sum (this returns None)
            break

find_next_sum(0,listt,0,0)
```

Comment: My code works in for finding all the possible valid cases. The problem I am facing is in ending the loop and make the function return when the first correct case is found.

Comment: checkout a similar example here --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-it-possible-to-partition-in-k-subarrays-with-equal-sum/